# Forward incoming data on specific port to both local port and external ip

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, iptables, linux-networking

i want to forward all data coming to specific port to local application listing on that port and as well as to external ip. is it possible to do it using iptables or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to mirror the traffic using External switch. One port can be connected to the machine that is running Local Application and other Port can be connected into a firewall that will forward it to the External IP address. However the return traffic can only come from one source (either Local Application or External IP address), so one of them will be just passive receiver.